# Should we provide a definition for a discarded function used by a discarded variable's initializer declaration in global module fragment?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

When I #include one header file in one module unit's global module fragment, I encountered some link error provided by MSVC and GCC together.

Firstly, I have one header file **"Header.h"** like this:

```
#pragma once
int f();

const int value = f();
```

And then, I defined a primary module interface unit **[m1.ixx OR m1.cpp]** like this:

```
module;
#include "Header.h"

export module m1;

export {
    inline int value2 = 0; // Not use anything in Header.h
}
```

Lastly, I import the module in **"main.cpp"** and build the example, the **"main.cpp"** like this:

```
import m1;
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << value2 << endl;
}
```

I got some link errors from GCC11:

> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccEkMykg.o: in function
> `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
>
> m1.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `f()'

and similarly link errors from MSVC:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  Study2  C:\Users\Glx\source\repos\Study2\x64\Debug\Study2.exe   1
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl f(void)" (?f@@YAHXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'value''(void)" (??__Evalue@@YAXXZ)  Study2  C:\Users\Glx\source\repos\Study2\Study2\m1.ixx.obj  1

In my understanding, the declaration of the variable **value** and the function **f()** should be **discarded** because they are the declarations in the **global module fragment**
and not be used by the module unit, **so it's okay even if I don't provide the definition for the function** **f()**.

**Did I understand it wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Discarded” in the context of modules just means that it’s not found by lookup from **template definitions** in the module (being instantiated as part of compiling a client).  It doesn’t mean the same thing as a discarded *statement* in `if constexpr`.  The definition of `value` plainly odr-uses `f`, so it must be defined somewhere.

Meanwhile, you shouldn’t have **internal-linkage** things like `value` in a header file at all.